# R Code to Create Flag with Specific Row Values

Tags: r

Is there a way to use R to Flag Values if there was a Call occurrence after a Text was sent?
The previous row should have "Text" as a Method than a "Call" based on the unique ID values.

[image: Original Data]

I need:

[image: Final Result]

My Code:

```
for (i in unique(textdata1$ClaimID1)) {
    if(textdata1$ContactMethod[i] == 'Email' && textdata1$ContactMethod[i+1] == 'Call'){
     textdata1$marker[i] <- "No"
        }else {
     textdata1$marker[i] <- "Yes"
       }
    }
```

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and not as images. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create the 'flag' by making use of a comparison with the `lag` of 'Method' after grouping by 'ID'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(Flag = +(Method == 'Call' & lag(Method, default = first(Method)) == 'Call'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign 1 when the current `Method == 'Call'` and the previous row was `'Text'`.

Using `data.table` this can be done as :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Flag := as.integer(Method == 'Call' & 
                    shift(Method, fill = first(Method)) == 'Text'), ID]
```